# PBKDF2WithSHA512-256 SecretKeyFactory not available error while using JDK11.0.17

Tags: java, security, java-11, pbkdf2, secretkeyfactory

We have recently upgraded to JDK 11.0.17 and when I try to call -

`SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithSHA512-256");`

I am getting the following exception -

`java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithSHA512-256 SecretKeyFactory not available`

The same code is working when I use JDK 11.0.1.
Has the behaviour changed with the JDK upgrade?
If so, can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: While some changes were done around this https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11all-relnotes.html#R11_0_17 , but that should not be the case .. can you elaborate the use case a little bit more ..

Comment: So basically we are trying to generatePBKDFKey with this algorithm, and using this call we get a SecretKeyFactory instance. Using this instance we can then generate the SecretKey by employing the generateSecret() method. 
This method was working so far, but since we performed the java upgrade it is failing with the above mentioned exception. We are also facing the same issue with JDK17 as well.